# column is unknown when the column and the table are defined?

Tags: mysql, sql

i stumbled upon this example :

```
SELECT SupplierName
FROM Suppliers
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ProductName FROM Products WHERE Products.SupplierID = Suppliers.supplierID );
```

it works with no problem and shows the requested rows, but when i tried to run the subquery as a query like this

```
SELECT ProductName FROM Products WHERE Products.SupplierID = Suppliers.supplierID ;
```

it tells me that Suppliers.supplierID is an unknown column, what am i missing ?

Comment: Well thats because it is, you have told the subquery Nothing about the `Suppliers` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You think the query is:

```
SELECT s.SupplierName
FROM Suppliers s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT p.ProductName
              FROM Products p
              WHERE p.SupplierID = s.supplierID
             );
```

But if `p.ProductName` does not exist, then SQL reaches out to the outer query and it is interpreted as:

```
SELECT s.SupplierName
FROM Suppliers s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT s.ProductName
              FROM Products p
              WHERE p.SupplierID = s.supplierID
             );
```

In this case, it makes no difference whatsoever, because `EXISTS` only checks for the existence of *rows*, not *columns*.  I usually write this using `SELECT 1`.

That said, it *can* make a difference in other contexts.  Hence, the moral still applies:

> Moral:  Always qualify all column references, especially in a query that has more than one table reference.